# Arduino Due with Atmel Studio 7

Tags: c++, arduino-due, atmel-studio

I was trying to switch to Atmel Studio for programming my Due project since it became more and more complex.
I managed to use the Arduino Importer Wizard to load a blink.ino file and included all the requested libraries more or less my hand that were marked as missing during compiling.
Now the compiling kind of works, but I still get this error:

```
Error       (inkerScript): No such file or directory    ECU arm-none-eabi-g++.exe   0
```

The `(inkerScript):` part is no typo. It is really like this in the console.
Taking a look in the Toolchain Options I have these settings (which I am not able to edit):
[image: Linker Options]

Going into the Miscellaneous Part of the Options I can edit these fields:
[image: Miscellaneous Options]

By editing the Linker Flags field, I can change the error message from `(inkerScript): No such file or directory` to e.g. `HelloWorld: No such file or directory`.

Is there anything wrong with my options? What is the correct setting for "Linker Flags" and what are they doing?

Unfortunately I am not a pro with C++ Compiling / Linker Errors / Settings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this.  After looking at other examples in the compiler command line options, it looks like it should be $(LinkerScript) instead of ($LinkerScript).

In Atmel Studio, go to project properties, toolchain, ARM/GNU Linker, Miscellaneous to find the option to change.